# Move the "Stacked/Grouped" selector on NVD3.js multiBarChart.js

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I would like to move the "Grouped/Stacked" selectors from where they are at the top of the chart to the bottom of [the chart](http://goo.gl/Hxl1r). Is this possible to do somehow?

Answer (score 0):

<del>A quick and easy way would be to add:</del>

<del>`d3.select(".nv-controlsWrap").attr("transform", "translate(0,620)")`</del>

<del>to after the set-up of the nvd3.js graph.</del>

You'll have to create a fork of nvd3 and alter:

https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/src/models/multiBarChart.js#L186-L189

eg:

```
    g.select('.nv-controlsWrap')
        .datum(controlsData)
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height +')')
        .call(controls);
```

Comment: I did the d3.select line you have, however, when I click on "grouped" to switch to the grouped view, the nv-controlsWrap goes back to the top.

Comment: Ah, true! You'll have to fork nvd3.js and modify the original source to change the positioning I'm afraid. That's the trade off you have to make when using a pre-defined solution.